# How to search the whole manual pages on Linux?

Tags: linux, man, search, documentation

Sometimes I need to look up certain words through all the manual pages. I am aware of `apropos`, but if I understand its manual right, it restricts search to the descriptions only.

> Each manual page has a short description available within it. apropos searches the descriptions for instances of keyword.

For example, if I look up a word like 'viminfo', I get no results at all...

```
$ apropos viminfo
viminfo: nothing appropriate.
```

... although this word exists in a later section of the manual of Vim (which is installed on my system).

> ```
>    -i {viminfo}
>                When  using  the  viminfo file is enabled, this option sets the filename to use, instead of the default "~/.vim‐
>                info".  This can also be used to skip the use of the .viminfo file, by giving the name "NONE".
> ```

So how can I look up a word through every section of every manual?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From [`man man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/man.1):

```
-K, --global-apropos
      Search for text in all manual  pages.   This  is  a  brute-force
      search,  and is likely to take some time; if you can, you should
      specify a section to reduce the number of pages that need to  be
      searched.   Search terms may be simple strings (the default), or
      regular expressions if the --regex option is used.
```

This directly opens the manpage (`vim`, then `ex`, then `gview`, ...)  for me, so you could add another option, like `-w` to get an idea of which manpage will be displayed.

```
$ man -wK viminfo
/usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/run-one.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gvim.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/run-one.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/run-one.1.gz
...
```

Comment: The -wK combination is particulaly interesting

Comment: If I do ``:!man -K info`` in gvim, will it let me edit the manual pages or will it merely display the manual pages? In VIM normal mode, I accidentally hit ``K`` when my cursor was at the word ``info`` and I was afaird that I may have messed up some of the manual pages (and hence this question) :-(

Answer (score 8):

Use the global apropos option in `man`.

```
 -K, --global-apropos
              Search for text in all manual pages.  This is a brute-force search, and is likely to take some time; if you can, you should specify a section to reduce the number  of pages that need to be searched.  Search terms may be simple strings (the default), or regular expressions if the --regex option is used.
```

So, `man -K viminfo` will give you the page you need.

Answer (score 1):

`NetBSD` has a full text search implementation of `apropos(1)` which does search across the complete content of man pages instead of restricting just to the `NAME` section. You might want to check it out.

There is a web based interface for it as well: [man-k.org](http://man-k.org)

---

**Disclaimer:** I am the developer of both of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man -K "fopen"
```

gives you the output

```
/usr/share/man/en/man3/fclose.3.gz? [ynq]
```

`y` to open/display man page

`n` to continue search

`q` to Quit search